# How do I print the results of the regular expression using findall?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Kinda new to regular expressions with Python, I am attempting to parse through the data below.

**The code**

```
thing = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'matchheader'})
thing1 = str(thing)
print(thing1)
```

Gives me

```
  1. GSL - <b>Global Ship Lease Inc</b> [N/A] - Matched DCIX from 07/27/16 to 12/01/16
  </div>, <div class="matchheader">
  2. SBGI - <b>Sinclair Broadcast Group, Inc.</b> [Media] - Matched DCIX from 07/27/16 to 12/01/16
  </div>, <div class="matchheader">
  3. WSTC - <b>West Corporation</b> [+2] - Matched DCIX from 07/27/16 to 12/01/16
  </div>, <div class="matchheader">
  4. TGNA - <b>TEGNA Inc.</b> [N/A] - Matched DCIX from 07/27/16 to 12/01/16
  </div>, <div class="matchheader">
  5. MLI - <b>MUELLER INDUSTRIES INC</b> [Manufacturing] - Matched DCIX from 07/27/16 to 12/01/16
```

Now for the regular expression

```
pattern = "([A-Z])[A-Z]{2,5}(?![A-Z])"
match = re.findall(pattern,thing1)
print(match)
```

The result I am expecting is

```
['GSL', 'SBGI', 'WSTC', 'TGNA', 'MLI']
```

But the result I am getting is

```
['G', 'D', 'S', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'T', 'T', 'D', 'M', 'U', 'S', 'I', 'D']
```

I am pretty sure that the second D is from the DCIX on the first line.

So is the problem the **regular expression pattern** I am using, using **re.findall**, or the **print(match)**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your current regex matches DCIX too, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/zU2q4J/3), try this one instead: [`\d+\. ([A-Z][A-Z]{2,5}(?![A-Z]))`](https://regex101.com/r/zU2q4J/4) in which group 1 matches want you want.

Comment: There is it! Thanks a lot @NicolasMaltais you are truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will match every group of consecutive upper case letters, and then return just the first letter of each group. Instead, you probably meant to return just the first of those groups, per line.

What you could do instead is to use the prefix `^.*?([A-Z]{2,5})` to find the shortest sequence at the start of the line `^.*?` (use `re.M` for multi-line mode) followed by a group of upper-case letters `([A-Z]{2,5})`, if any, and then return that group.

```
>>> re.findall("^.*?([A-Z]{2,5})", thing1, re.M)
['GSL', 'SBGI', 'WSTC', 'TGNA', 'MLI']
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of wrapped text, or to be sure that we get the second line element (if the class name is empty), I suggest to check if the number at the line begining exists, and use following regular expression:

```
r"^[0-9]+[^\w]+([A-Z]{2,5})"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ain't entirely sure, but perhaps what you want is soup.text? i.e:

```
for item in thing:
    thing1=item.text
    print(thing1)
```

However, I would do it like this:

```
thing=soup.select('div.matchheader') #returns a list of divs that have a css class 'matchheader'
thing1_list=[]
for item in thing:
    thing1_list.append(item.getText())
```

Hope that helps